# MongoDB: How to find and replace ObjectId across collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm merging two documents into one. For that, I want to replace all references to DocA with references to DocB.

I want to do this for all documents and all collections within a database. Across collections/models, every reference to this type of document uses the same key, "docFieldKey." However the path is often different so sometimes it's at the top-level, sometimes in an array of objects within the document.

```
ExModelA: {
   _id: ObjectId,
   docFieldKey: string // if docAId, replace with docBId
}
```

The reference to docA could be in a subfield like:

```
ExModelB: {
   _id: ObjectId,
   someKey: {
       docFieldKey: string // if docAId, replace with docBId
   }
}
```

DocAId could be even deeper like in an array of objects.

```
ExModelC: {
   _id: ObjectId,
   someKey: [{
       docFieldKey: string // if docAId, replace with docBId
       otherKey: any
   }]
}
```

I want to find all fields called "docFieldKey," check their value, and if docAId then replace with docBId. What's the easiest way of doing this? Is there a mongoose query that could do the heavy lifting?

Note: I anticipate periodically needing to replace documents in the system so I'm trying to make this script for an arbitrary docFieldKey so that it's reusable.

Comment: Do you want to merge two documents or collections?

Comment: Two documents. DocA is being replaced by DocB. I need to replace all ObjectId references to DocA with ObjectId references to DocB then I'll just remove DocA.

Comment: Just a minute. I am editing my ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this on our NodeJS server. To run, just call 'replaceDocument.' If people find it useful, I may make it into an npm package. I haven't seen this functionality anywhere.

```
let toReplace = null;
let replacement = null;
let searchKey = null;

function replaceReferencesInDoc(document) {
  let mongooseUpdateObject = null;

  function checkForSearchKey(anyType, path, currentKey) {

    if (currentKey === searchKey && anyType + "" === toReplace + "") {

      if (!mongooseUpdateObject) mongooseUpdateObject = {};
      mongooseUpdateObject[path] = replacement;

    } else if (typeof anyType === "object" && anyType !== null && !Array.isArray(anyType)) {

      const keys = Object.keys(anyType);

      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {

        checkForSearchKey(anyType[keys[i]], `${path}${path !== "" ? "." : ""}${keys[i]}`, keys[i]);
      }

    } else if (Array.isArray(anyType)) {

      for (let i = 0; i < anyType.length; i += 1) {

        checkForSearchKey(anyType[i], `${path}${path !== "" ? "." : ""}${i}`, i);
      }
    }

  }

  checkForSearchKey(document, "", "");

  if (mongooseUpdateObject) {
    console.log(`update object for ${document._id}`, mongooseUpdateObject);
  }

  return mongooseUpdateObject;

}

async function replaceReferencesInCollection(model) {

  const allDocuments = await model.find().lean().exec();

  const replacementPromises = [];

  for (let j = 0; j < allDocuments.length; j += 1) {

    const update = replaceReferencesInDoc(allDocuments[j]);

    if (update) {
      replacementPromises.push(
        model.update({ _id: allDocuments[j]._id }, update).exec(),
      );
    }
  }

  await Promise.all(replacementPromises);

}

async function runReplaceDocument(toReplaceParam, replacementParam, searchParam, arrayOfModels) {
  try {

    toReplace = toReplaceParam;
    replacement = replacementParam;
    searchKey = searchParam;

    const start = new Date().getTime();

    console.log(`searching for ${searchKey} = ${toReplace} to replace with ${replacement}`);
    console.log(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfModels.length; i += 1) {
      console.log(`--- checking collection ${arrayOfModels[i].collection.collectionName} ---`);
      await replaceReferencesInCollection(arrayOfModels[i]); //eslint-disable-line
      console.log(" ");
    }

    console.log(`replace took ${(new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000} seconds`);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write the query for the mongo shell. On the mongo shell, it will run too fast and easily.

Sample of query -

```
db.loans.find({ _id: docA },function (DocAA) {
 db.loans.find({ _id: docB },function (DocBB) {
  print("DocAA: " + DocAA._id + "DocBB: " + DocBB._id);
  db.loans.update({ _id: docA }, { $set: { _deleted: true } });
});
db.loans.remove({ _id: docB});
});
```

Comment: That looks like it's going to remove all documents that reference DocA. I want to replace those references with DocB.

Comment: Check now. That was the reference not query for u.

Comment: In this query write $set according to you.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to figure this out. I think we're not understanding each other though. I tried making the question more clear.